# Vue vs Livewire. Что лучше использовать для небольших компонентов?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, livewire

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильнее сделать, ситуация такая:

Для проекта очень важна скорость первой загрузки страницы, соотвественно js кода писать нужно как можно меньше, и вес страницы должен быть маленьким.

——————

Есть компонент, для примера это будет меню с ссылками на страницы личного кабинета: настройки, выход и.т.д.

При клике на свою аватарку пользователю нужно показывать меню.

Вижу 3 варианта реализации этого функционала:

1. Используя livewire. Плюс этого подхода в том что на странице
   изначально не будет лишнего компонента. Минус что нужно ждать его
   загрузку.
2. Загрузить компонент на странице и показывать его через кастомную функцию на js.
3. Загрузит и компонент и vue. (От такого подхода мы ушли в пользу livewire)

Comment: При правильном написании приложени и разумном кешировании статики первая отрисовка вью может произойти менее чем через 100мс.

Comment: @VasiliyRusin когда приложение не большое - да

Comment: А чем отличается большое приложение от небольшого? Вы же грузите не все приложение разом, а только запрашиваемую страницу.

Comment: тем что в больших приложениях собираються больше зависимостей, которые грузятся на всех страницах

Comment: Все зависимости грузятся лишь один раз в chunk-vendors.js, Ваш вопрос о том как правильно делать если важна скорость отрисовки, ответ - использовать JS фраемвок с разумным делнием кода и кешированием. Когда страница вашего приложения уже закеширована на клиенте пользователя она откроется практически мгновенно. 

Статистика реального проекта:
35К строк кода
300мс до первой отрисовки

Comment: наверное не поняли сутьвопроса, кеширование на клиенте не спасает, важна скорость загрузки именно первого визита

потому что основной потом траффика идет из поисковых систем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришёл к выводу что Livewire и Vue не подходят под такие "мелкие" фронтэнд задачи.

Остановился на [Alpine.js](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine), это лёгкая библиотека именно для таких целей. Ещё её разрабатывает и поддерживает создатель Livewire.